# undefined return from a class constructor -- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have one file which is block.js:

```
class Block{
    constructor(timeStamp, lastBlockHash, thisBlockData, thisBlockHash){
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.lastBlockHash = lastBlockHash;
        this.thisBlockData = thisBlockData; 
        this.thisBlockHash = thisBlockHash;
        }

    static genesis(){
        return new this(Date.now(), "---", "genesis block", "hash of the genesis");
    }
}
```

I have another file blockchain.js where I have the following:

```
const Block = require('./block');
class BlockChain{
    constructor() {
       this.chain = BlockInstance.genesis();
    }
}
```

and i have a test file where I am doing:

```
const Block = require("./block.js");
const BlockChain = require("./blockchain.js");
console.log(BlockChain.chain);
```

I get a "undefined" object in the print output.. this is really driving me nuts as i have already spent more than 4 hours on it.. 
if anyone can solve this mystery for me then a round of beers on me..

Cheers,
alchemist

Comment: I think you have to still instantiate the classes and not just require them.

Comment: You don't create any instance in your code. You need to use the `new` keyword for creating a `BlockChain` instance. The class itself doesn't have `chain` property, it's instances have!

Comment: you guys are right.. thanks a million.. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate the classes like

```
const Block = require("./block.js");
const BlockChain = require("./blockchain.js");
let block = new Block(...);
let blockChain = new BlockChain();
console.log(blockChain.chain);
```

For an example of building a blockchain with JS, you may want to follow a site like [This one from medium](https://medium.com/@spenserhuang/learn-build-a-javascript-blockchain-part-1-ca61c285821e)

The `genesis()` method would be more suited to be a part of the chain since that is a property of a chain not a different type of block.

Comment: Hi Daniel.. it is somehow still not working.. :/ this is my dev-test.js script so far:    
                                                                                                                                
   const Block = require("./block.js");
const BlockChain= require("./blockchain.js");


let blockInstance = new Block();
let blockChainInstance = new BlockChain();


console.log(blockInstance.mineBlock(blockInstance.Genesis(), "First Block Afer Geneis"));
console.log(blockChainInstance.chain);

Comment: thanks for replying.. lets say i am writing a test case to just test blockchain.js.. and i forget completely about block.js.. since when i instantiate blockchaininstance the constructor inside it with this code: this.chain= Block.genesis() should create a genesis block..

Comment: great.. thanks a million :))  on a final note.. Block.genesis() cannot be called without instantiating the Block class directly? because if i do console.log with Block.genesis() it works.. because inside genesis function i have " return new this()" which instantiates block...

Comment: That should be done if it was a static method, but I would strongly encourage you to move the genesis() to the BlockChain class over the Block class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180269/discussion-between-thealchemist-and-daniel-gale).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is syntactical binding. You need to instantiate your `BlockChain` class like this:

```
const myBlockChain = new BlockChain();
console.log(myBlockChain.chain);
```

Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Boxing_with_prototype_and_static_methods) for more info on this.